# How can huge REST API response be handled in AWS component?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

The requirement is to fire a REST API, get the response (reasonably large) and save the response to S3. What is the recommended approach to get this done? (using Lamda/Step Function/EC2 app?)

Comment: How large is the large? you can use AWS Batch instead of lambda for the heavy stuff.

Comment: If you have a trigger condition to make that process fire, a Lambda function would do it **at first glance**. It also may not, as the question does not put the desired structure thoroughly.

Comment: large - lets assume 50,000 records in the response.

Comment: You have Amazon Cloudwatch to storage that responses

Comment: more than storage, how can it the response be received and parsed effectively?